# ant task hangs when executing init.d script on debian

Tags: shell, ant, debian

I've an init.d script for starting a java process on debian squeeze. if I call this script in an ant ant build like:

```
<target name="deploy-CdrServer-local">
            <ant antfile="${CdrServer.location}/build.xml" target="deploy-local" inheritAll="false">
                    <property name="basedir" value="${CdrServer.location}" />
            </ant>
            <exec dir="/etc/init.d" spawn="false" executable="bash" newenvironment="false">
                    <arg line="cdrserver restart"/>
            </exec>
    </target>
```

the script is executed but than ant "hangs" after the following output:

```
 [copy] Copying 1 file to /opt/CdrServer
 [copy] Copying 7 files to /opt/CdrServer/CdrServer_lib
 [exec] Stopping CdrServer ...
 [exec] CdrServer server process stopped
 [exec] Starting CdrServer ... 
 [exec] cat $PIDFILE
 [exec] CdrServer has PID:  24170
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] restarted CdrServer
 [exec] exit 0
```

I've seen in the ant docu that setting inputstring="" as parameter would help, but it doesnt ...

Any ideas?

Comment: The init.d scripts normally run as root. Could that be an issue?

Comment: In my demo environment I run also ant as root, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that ant hangs on solaris when executing a script that spawns a background child process.

To fix it, I altered the script so that it spat out a file "yes I am done". Then I altered the ant file to delete that file, exec the script with spawn-"true", and then waitfor that file to be present.